# Visualizing Prime cyclical data

Tags: graphics, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I'm not too familiar with Mathematica graphics, but I would like to produce a "ring-list" with other lists point to a center list. Here is an example list of the many I've generated (each list is infinite, I think):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
    \{2,5,11,23,47,19,13,3,7\} \\
    \{3,7,5,11,23,47,19,13\} \\
    \{5,11,23,47,19,13,3,7\} \\
    \{7,5,11,23,47,19,13,3\} \\
    \{11,23,47,19,13,3,7,5\} \\
    \{13,3,7,5,11,23,47,19\} \\
    \{17,7,5,11,23,47,19,13,3\} \\
    \{19,13,3,7,5,11,23,47\} \\
    \{23,47,19,13,3,7,5,11\} \\
    \{29,59,17,7,5,11,23,47,19,13,3\} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

*it won't let me put in the LaTeX because it appears as code.

As you can tell, there are duplicates in this list. The first list is the "root" cycle. I would like all of the other lists to point, respectively, to there belonging connection to this "root" list.

Here is the type of thing I'm envisioning:

[image: sketch]

Pardon my poor paint skills (and lack of knowledge). If you're curious, I'm generating arithmetic prime sequences with the following algorithm:

```
primeCycle[x_] := Module[{},
cycleList = {};
h = x;
AppendTo[cycleList, h];
h = Last[FactorInteger[2*h + 1]][[1]];
While[! MemberQ[cycleList, h], {AppendTo[cycleList, h], h = 
Last[FactorInteger[2*h + 1]][[1]];}];
cycleList
]
```

I plan on investigating more than $2\cdot h+1$, but I'm not able to compile enough data by hand. The hope is that maybe I learn something interesting.

I believe that for any function $A\cdot h \pm b$, ($A$ is prime and $b<(A-1)/2)$, there is always a "root" cycle (as depicted above).

I also think it may be interesting to investigate other functional forms, but I plan on sticking with simple functions for now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast your results into a directed graph as follows:

```
data = primeCycle /@ Prime[Range[100]];

Graph[
 DirectedEdge @@@ Union @@ Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, data],
 VertexLabels -> "Name",
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: How can I make the labels the values at that point instead of the index? (To make it identical to the drawing I made). Awesome, I should have figured it was "name" but I wasn't positive.

Comment: Good point. It should read `VertexLabels -> "Name". (Fixed it also in the post).

Comment: Henrik, this is super fascinating! Thank you so much, it would have taken me a long time to be able to compile these graphs on my own. I can very easily see that my conjecture was false! There are more than one "rings" for different $An+B$

Comment: Yeah, testing conjectures this way is a very mature approach. It's good to hear that you put this to good use!